# Problem with Integrating Wagtail into a Django project

Tags: django

I built a test wagtail project with its own app that interact with Django. This is the GH repo: https://github.com/progettazionemauro/django-wiki-wag .What I want is to populate django admin panel with some data that after can be injected into wagtail app.I added in django admin panel the specific panel to feed the wagtail data but there is a problem. So in conclusion I have 2 routes: (Django admin) http://127.0.0.1/admin/ and (Wagtail admin): http://127.0.0.1/wagtail-admin) If I run python3 manage.py runserver at django level (Django admin) I am able to see the brand new admin panel integrated in Django admin, but I am not able to see the Wagtail Dashboard with the pages already created (I see a brand new Wagtail Dashboard)2) If I run python3 manage.py runserver at wagtail level (Wagtail admin) I am able to see wagtail pages I already created, but I am not able to see the Django admin panel with the the brand new admin pane created specific for wagtail (I see only Django admin panel)So I found the documentation and I cleaned the cache, restarted the server, but the problem persists and it seems not related to the memory or something like that. Moreover it seems related to an issue related to interaction between wagtail and Django.Any help is appreciatedThanks in advanceMauro